# Is random measure just a probability disribution up to a constant?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

a probability measure is where we assign values in [0,1) to elements that are part of the $\sigma $algebra of the events space.

Is a random measure $\mu(A), A\in\sigma\text{algebra }$the same but assigning values that are in a range $[0,c], c<\infty$, such that $\mu/c$ is a probability distribution?

Please avoid as much measure theory as possible in explaination. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that $c< \infty$ is not ensured. Such measures are called *finite measures*. The simplest example of an infinite measure is the usual measure on the real numbers

Comment: 1. To a probability measure we assign values in $[0,1\color{red}]$. 2. A [random measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_measure) is strictly speaking a measure valued random variable. 3. What you have called random measure is normally just called a measure.